# extract a specific range of fasta sequences from a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, command-line, fasta

I am trying to extract sequences from a specific range. the command that I am using can only extract the first n lines in a fasta sequence

```
awk "/^>/ {n++} n>2000 {exit} {print}" Name.faa > Name_2k_cds.faa
```

If i want to extract sequences from a specific range like 2000 to 3000, how can I do that? is there a simple edit in my existing code.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know. Special thanks for posting your efforts in your question though.

Comment: Could you please check my answer and lemme know if that helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sed -n '2000,3000p' Name.faa > Name_2k_to_3k_cds.faa
```

*explanation:*

```
sed -n       # suppress automatic printing of pattern space
'2000,3000p' # print only line 2000 to 3000
```

Comment: IMHO, If I got the question correctly, OP doesn't want to print from line numbers. OP wants to count lines which are starting from `>` and that count's line numbers from 2000 to 3000 he/she needs.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/^>/{n++} n>=2000 && n<=3000;n==3000{exit}' Name.faa > Name_2k_cds.faa
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
/^>/{n++}                         ##Checking condition if a line starts from > then do following.
n>=2000 && n<=3000                ##Checking condition if value of n is greater than or equal than 2000 AND lesser than or equal to 3000 then print that line.
n==3000{                          ##Checking condition if value of n is 3000 then exit from this program, NO NEED to read whole Input_file since we need only 2000 to 3000 lines only.   
  exit                            ##Using exit to exit from code.
}
' Name.faa > Name_2k_cds.faa      ##Mentioning Input_file name and re-directing its output to another output file.
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight addition to the solution proposed by @RavinderSingh13

```
awk '/^>/{n++} n>=2000 && n<=3000;n==3001{exit}' Name.faa > Name_2k_cds.faa
```

This ensures that sequence 3000 is also stored in the new file, whereas the original solution's output extracts the title for sequence 3000, but not the sequence itself.